# How to do a this with a component in react native?

Tags: javascript, react-native, components, this

I am working with react native and expo.cli and would like to know how I can manage to add a handle to a TouchableOpacity, I have the following component:

```
function MainModal (){
return(
    <>
      <View style={{flexDirection: 'row'}}>
        <TouchableOpacity
            onPress={this.TouchableOpacity}
            > 
            <Text>Volver</Text>
        </TouchableOpacity>

      </View>
    </>
```

What I want to do is make a reference to this specific **TouchableOpacity** when it is selected, but when I use a **"this"** nested in the component I get the following error: *Undefined is not an object (Evaluating 'this.TouchableOpacity')* I know maybe This question is a bit of a novice and has more to do with how 'this' works in javascript than with React Native itself, however I can't find a way to make a reference to the selected object so that it executes something when selected. How could I do it?

Answer (score 1):

You can use `React.useRef()` hook to create a reference to that element so you can access then to it. The idea you have of `this` is not the actual `this`. `This` might refer to the global object (in not strict) and might be undefined in strict mode. If you want to use `this` in a component I recommend you to create a `class` component instead of a function one. See [this in MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/this) to learn more of it.
Anyway, the use of ref in a functional component would be this:

```
function MainModal (){

const touchableReference = React.useRef()

const handleTouchableClick = () => {
  console.log(touchableReference.current)
  //
  // Outputs HTMLDivElement...
  //
}

return(
    <>
      <View style={{flexDirection: 'row'}}>
        <TouchableOpacity
            ref={touchableReference}
            onPress={() => handleTouchableClick()}
            > 
            <Text>Volver</Text>
        </TouchableOpacity>

      </View>
    </>
  )
}
```

Answer (score 0):

One standard way of passing event handler in functional component is as follows

```
function MainModal (props){
const onPress1 = useCallback(()=>console.log); // created inside the componet
const {onPress2} = props; // passed from props
const {onPress3} = useSomeHook(); // from context/hook
return(
    <>
      <View style={{flexDirection: 'row'}}>
        <TouchableOpacity
            onPress={onPress1}
            > 
            <Text>Volver</Text>
        </TouchableOpacity>
        <TouchableOpacity
            onPress={onPress2}
            > 
            <Text>Volver</Text>
        </TouchableOpacity>
        <TouchableOpacity
            onPress={onPress3}
            > 
            <Text>Volver</Text>
        </TouchableOpacity>
      </View>
    </>
);
}
```

The behaviour of `this` works the same in react and react-native. React functional component is executed during the render phase and you are not suppose to work with `this` here, given that you do not understand when and where it is called.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/this